# When starting rails server "Uncaught exception: no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I Updated the output to make it more readable.  Still getting this error.

Noob question.  Has anyone else seen this error? This error seems to be spreading.  It now happens for port 3000 and 3001.  If I change the code and debug settings to 3002 then I can continue debugging.

### --------------------------------------------------------------

### -------------------------------------------------------------

```
$: rails s -p 3000
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
Exiting
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@ats/gems/eventmachine-1.0.8/lib/eventmachine.rb:534:in `start_tcp_server': no acceptor (port is in use or requires root privileges) (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: a server is already running on port 3000 can you do ps aux | grep rails and paste the result

Comment: $: ps ax | grep rails

Comment: 4141 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto rails

Answer (score 2):

run

`ps ax | grep rails`

this will return the process number of the rails server currently running

then you can do 

`kill -9 *process_numer*`

this answer assumes that you accidentally quit rails server by pressing Ctrl+Z instead of Ctrl+C which did no dispose of the process properly and is now tying up the port.

Comment: Nothing returns. Even tried grep -i, still nothing.  Rails server is not running.

Comment: try 'lsof -i :3000' then 'kill -9 *pid*' the PID you will see returned from first command

Comment: that command returns nothing.  I did 'lsof -i' and killed everything listed.  Server still will not start on port 3000.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when some process is already using that port.

Usually this happens when rails server is already started (for example - for other project, and you forgot to stop it)

Use `ps ax | grep rails | grep -v grep` and `lsof -n -i4TCP:3000 | grep LISTEN` to find rails servers and processes using port 3000